# HTML Action ID get method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, yii

This may already be a copy of another question but I cant find it.

I have an action in my form:

```
<form id="bug-form" action="/AST_14/Bugg.ly2/index.php/bug/update/" method="post">
```

Now the way my system works is the each of the "bugs" that need updating have there own bug id, Normally this would go onto the end of the bug ID to allow the user to update said Bug.

I have some json code being created in Yii to display the bug ID, and the edit. 
The issue is that when I click the edit. It goes to a page that doesn't have the ID on the form. I need some way of getting that ID to move across to the form.

Here is all the code that I have for the form.

```
<!--PAGE -->

<div data-role="page" id="Reg">
<header role="banner" data-role="header" id="header" style="height:45px; z-    index:1"> <a data-icon="back" data-role="button" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-    left backToAdmin">Back</a> </header>

 <!--Initial Home Screen Logo-->
<section data-role="content" class="constrain headerLogo" > </section>

<!--Main Content in Center of Screen-->
<section data-role="content" class="sectionContent constrain"> 

  <!--960 Grid Root [responsive web design plugin]-->
  <div class="container_16" data-theme="a">
    <div class="grid_16">
    <div class="gridMarginsLeft">
      <ul id="viewProps" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="a" data-icon="false" class="">
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="a"><span class="icon-data fontIcons"></span><span class="coloumnHeaders">Update</span></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="a">


<form id="bug-form" action="/AST_14/Bugg.ly2/index.php/bug/update/" method="post">
<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>


<div class="row">
        <label for="Bug_bugname">Bugname</label>        <textarea rows="6" cols="50" name="Bug[bugname]" id="Bug_bugname">1</textarea>          </div>

<div class="row">
    <label for="Bug_BugType">Bug Type</label>       <input name="Bug[BugType]" id="Bug_BugType" type="text" value="1">          </div>

<div class="row">
    <label for="Bug_Bugaddress">Bugaddress</label>      <input size="60" maxlength="255" name="Bug[Bugaddress]" id="Bug_Bugaddress" type="text" value="1">          </div>

<div class="row">
    <label for="Bug_description">Description</label>        <textarea rows="6" cols="50" name="Bug[description]" id="Bug_description">1</textarea>          </div>

<div class="row">
    <label for="Bug_admin_id">Admin</label>     <input name="Bug[admin_id]" id="Bug_admin_id" type="text" value="1">            </div>

<div class="row">
    <label for="Bug_status">Status</label>      <input size="3" maxlength="3" name="Bug[status]" id="Bug_status" type="text" value="1">         </div>

<div class="row">
    <label for="Bug_type">Type</label>      <input size="20" maxlength="20" name="Bug[type]" id="Bug_type" type="text" value="1">           </div>

<div class="row">
    <label for="Bug_vendors_id">Vendors</label>     <input name="Bug[vendors_id]" id="Bug_vendors_id" type="text" value="1">            </div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <input type="submit" name="yt0" value="Save">   </div>

</form>




        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden input to the form. I fthe id were in a variable name $id:

```
form id="bug-form" action="/AST_14/Bugg.ly2/index.php/bug/update/" method="post">

<input type="hidden"  name="id" value="$id" />

</form>
```

To put the id in the URL path, append $id to the action path.

```
form id="bug-form" action="/AST_14/Bugg.ly2/index.php/bug/update/$id" method="post">
```

Comment: Would this then change the url to 

`form id="bug-form" action="/AST_14/Bugg.ly2/index.php/bug/update/BUGIDHERE" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden input field tag inside your form and put the id as its value.

`<input type="hidden" id="bug_id" name="bug_id" value="$id" />`

And use javascript/jquery code to change your action url(Here I have used jquery):

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $('#bug-form').submit(function(){

    //append your bug id to the action url
    var updateUrl =  $(this).attr('action') +$('#bug_id').val();

    //update your action url of the form
    $(this).attr('action',updateUrl);
    });
```

});